# c++ uncaught exceptions on osX

Tags: c++, macos, exception

I have a problem with a c++ library that I develop: I defined my own exception class (that basically only contains a string to return for the what() call) and when an exception is not caught, the goal is that the operating system would print the message from what() and terminate. This works well on Linux but on osX, the exception message is not shown (ie it directly terminates without printing anything).

So, am I correctly assuming that uncaught exceptions would lead to what() followed by a termination? What should I do on osX so the message would be shown? (knowing that I don't like the idea of setting an exception handler, since this imposes the user of the library to do it)

Thanks!
Mathias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, am I correctly assuming that uncaught exceptions would lead to what() followed by a termination?

No. The standards don't require uncaught exceptions to print out `what()`. In fact, they make it pretty hard (but not impossible) to write a conforming implementation that always does so.

There's really no good way to do *exactly* what you want to do (print out the `what()`, only if the implementation isn't going to do so in this case, then carry on to `terminate()` as if the exception had never been caught). But that probably isn't what you really want.

This is probably what you want:

```
#import <exception>
#import <iostream>

int real_main(int argc, char *argv[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  try {
    return real_main(argc, argv);
  } catch (std::exception &e) {
    std::cerr << "exception: e.what()" << "\n";
    exit(1);
  } catch (...) {
    std::cerr << "exception not derived from std::exception\n";
    exit(1);
  }
}

int real_main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // real main code goes here
}
```

If you really want to, say, `_exit` or `abort` (or even `terminate`) instead of `exit`ing, you can do that of course. But if you don't know, you probably want `exit`.

Meanwhile:

> … knowing that I don't like the idea of setting an exception handler, since this imposes the user of the library to do it

You're writing a library? And you want your library to be able to terminate the process behind the application's back?

That's probably a very bad idea.

But if you really do want to do it, the same code above will work, you just have to wrap it around the entry points to your library instead of around `main`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations! I guess that I'll have to let the users of the library wrap it in try/catch blocks. Regarding the fact that the library throws exceptions, I don't see any other options: for example, if a the application requests getting some data from a data source that happens not to exist, it seems to me that throwing an exception (and letting the application catch it if it can handle the data not being available) is what exceptions are for (since I have a long data path otherwise, that would make it very painful to bring return code all the way back to the application)...

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly reasonable for a C++ library to throw exceptions, and it's not up to your library to detect whether they'll be caught and displayed. A developer should be able to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

On all OS's: catch the exception in `main()` and print out whatever message is appropriate. If you don't catch it, it is unspecified whether destructors are run on the way out. Do you really want that?